# How to create timer loop in python cv.PutText

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to figure out how to use timer loop in cv.putText.
This is what I have so far:

```
def draw_result(self, frame, result):
    x,y,w,h = self.metrics
    c = self.get_colour()

    cv.PutText(frame, "%0.0f"%result, (x+15,y-15), self.large_font_outline, c[1])
    cv.PutText(frame, "%0.0f"%result, (x+15,y-15), self.large_font, c[0])
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want more clearly and show what you've tried to make it work?

Comment: actually i have written a code to display the value present in the result, the value gets updated and repeatedly continuously i just want to print the value in the certain time interval say 30 secs so i need to know how to use timer in the cv.putText so that i can print the value in output image

Answer (score 0):

You can use time.time().

```
import time
inittime = time.time()
secs = 30
while 1:
    if time.time() >= inittime+secs:
        inittime = time.time()
        draw_result(self, frame, result)
```

this code will call draw_result in the last line every 30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i want to print result on the image which i have captured from webcam so im using cv.putText but the above code works only to print the result in cmd prompt